# FireBase sending Tokens to server

Tags: android

How to send token to server in Firebase cloud messaging.I have tried the following code:

```
public void onTokenRefresh() {
// Get updated InstanceID token.
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

// TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
```

But there is an error as sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken); is not defined.

Comment: You are supposed to create that method yourself just like with GCM.

Answer (score 2):

`sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken)` means to store the token into your own server. Which would be useful if you wanted to send message from your server to some certain users, or if you wanted to send a message from Firebase Console into a single device.